# MS SQL Combining 5 columns to 3 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to figure out how to combine 5 columns to 3 columns and avoiding duplicities at the same time.
I have been thinking about it for a few days and I can't figure out any solution so far, so I have decided to ask for help here.

Basically right now we use 5 columns in our database let's say A,B,C,D,E and somebody from our company has decided that we will be moving this information to new 3 columns let's call them NEW_1,NEW_2,NEW_3, because there are no cases when we would have more than 3 values per row in the DB.

I need to somehow extract those 5 columns and get them to just 3 columns without repeating them.

[image: Here is an example of how it should probably look]

So far I was thinking about and trying using CASE, but I can't figure it out how to stop it from showing the same value in all 3 NEW columns. I was thinking about assigning some variables to determine which columns to skip in select CASE, but I have found out that I can't do it like that.

If someone could at least direct me to the right way I would really appreciate it.

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN A is not null THEN A
    WHEN B is not null THEN B
    WHEN C is not null THEN C
    WHEN D is not null THEN D
    WHEN E is not null THEN E
    ELSE NULL
END as NEW_1,
CASE 
    WHEN B is not null THEN B
    WHEN C is not null THEN C
    WHEN D is not null THEN D
    WHEN E is not null THEN E
    ELSE NULL
END as NEW_2,
CASE 
    WHEN C is not null THEN C
    WHEN D is not null THEN D
    WHEN E is not null THEN E
    ELSE NULL
END as NEW_3
```

Comment: USE COALESCE function

Comment: Sample data as text, rather than a picture, would be helpful. Unless you're looking for a picture of the query....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like John's answer and probably better than mine, but here's a slightly different version if the columns are fixed to a specific number.

Build a delimited string of the column values, then use xml to extract the 1st, 2nd, 3rd values.

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([A] varchar(50),[B] varchar(50),[C] varchar(50),[D] varchar(50),[E] varchar(50));
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,2,3,NULL,NULL),(NULL,4,NULL,5,NULL),(NULL,null,6,7,8),(9,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);

WITH CTE AS (
SELECT CASE WHEN a IS NULL THEN '' ELSE a + '~' END +
       CASE WHEN b IS NULL THEN '' ELSE b + '~' END +
       CASE WHEN c IS NULL THEN '' ELSE c + '~' END +
       CASE WHEN d IS NULL THEN '' ELSE d + '~' END +
       CASE WHEN e IS NULL THEN '' ELSE e + '~' END AS Combined
FROM @YourTable
)
SELECT
ISNULL(CAST(N'<x>' + REPLACE(Combined, '~', N'</x><x>') + N'</x>' AS XML).value('/x[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), '') [new_1],
ISNULL(CAST(N'<x>' + REPLACE(Combined, '~', N'</x><x>') + N'</x>' AS XML).value('/x[2]', 'nvarchar(max)'), '') [new_2],
ISNULL(CAST(N'<x>' + REPLACE(Combined, '~', N'</x><x>') + N'</x>' AS XML).value('/x[3]', 'nvarchar(max)'), '') [new_3]
FROM CTE;
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Here is a option where we unpivot the data and then apply a conditional aggregation within a CROSS APPLY

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([A] varchar(50),[B] varchar(50),[C] varchar(50),[D] varchar(50),[E] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,2,3,NULL,NULL)
,(NULL,4,NULL,5,NULL)
,(NULL,null,6,7,8)
,(9,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)

Select A.*
      ,B.* 
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( 
  Select Val1 = max(case when ColNr=1 then Value end)
        ,Val2 = max(case when ColNr=2 then Value end)
        ,Val3 = max(case when ColNr=3 then Value end)
    From (
          Select ColNr = row_number() over (order by Seq)
                ,B1.*
           From  (values (1,A)
                        ,(2,B)
                        ,(3,C)
                        ,(4,D)
                        ,(5,E)
                   ) B1(Seq,Value)
            Where Value is not null
         ) B2
    ) B
```

**Returns**

[image]

**Just for Fun, here is an XML version**

```
Select A.*
      ,Val1 = XMLData.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')
      ,Val2 = XMLData.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')
      ,Val3 = XMLData.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values ( convert(xml,
                        concat('<x>'+A+'</x>'
                              ,'<x>'+B+'</x>'
                              ,'<x>'+C+'</x>'
                              ,'<x>'+D+'</x>'
                              ,'<x>'+E+'</x>'
                              ) ) ) ) B(XMLData)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am trying to understand it and apply it. I have to admit that this level of SQL is way above me.

Comment: @user3125275 Always happy to help.  Trust me when I say that I never do this, but your choice of accepted answer is perhaps the least performant method.

Comment: @Jon Capelletti I trust you about the performance issues of the method that I have chosen and I am sorry if by accepting the other answer I have offended you. I am not really familiar with several things that you have used in your solution and I still had to adjust the query for my purposes as I can't really share an exact example of what I need due to privacy policies. Even though the solution I have chosen is not the fastest, I at least understand it enough to adjust it and apply it for my purpose.

Comment: @user3125275 No offense, just concern that you may adopt a method which can be expensive ... both to your system and your reputation as a coder.   To be clear Rep Points mean nothing in the real world.  We do this solve problems and advance the skills of those asking questions.